# D3 bisect dates always returns 0 or 30

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 line graph I am trying to build. The x axis consists of dates. I want to track the mouse and return the date and price at the position of the mouse. I am have trouble with the bisector function.

```
const x = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.datetime))
      .range([0, width]);

const data = [
 {datetime: Fri Aug 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time), close: "149.10001"}, 
{datetime: Thu Aug 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time), close: "148.89000"},
{datetime: Wed Aug 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time), close: "145.86000"},
{datetime: Tue Aug 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time), close: "145.60001"},
...
    ];

const bisect = d3.bisector((d) => d.datetime).left;

const mousemove = () => {
const x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(e)[0]); ----->returns datetime value
let i = bisect(data, x0, 1); ----->always returns 1 or 30 (30 === data.length)
let d1 = data[i]; 
 ....
}
```

The bisect function always returns 1 or 30 but never any other value. My best guess is that I am formatting the dates wrong but I haven't been able to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who may have the same issue:

I was sorting the data like so

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.datetime -  a.datetime
    });
```

It was not working because d3's bisector function only works on data thats been sorted in ASCENDING order.

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.datetime - b.datetime;
    });
```

This fixed the problem.